# Null value transformed in function call

Tags: r

I encountered some strange behaviour that I don't quite understand. I often set non-required parameters as `NULL` in a function, so that I can check them using `is(!missing)`.

However, when I have one function pass a `NULL` value to another function, the `NULL` value gets interpreted as non-`NULL`:

```
fun1 <- function(value=NULL){
  if (missing(value)) stop("\n[!] Must provide a value. Exiting.")
  cat("Value is missing: ", missing(value), "value: ", value, "\n")
}

wrapper <- function(value=NULL){
  ret <- fun1(value=value)
  cat(ret)
}

wrapper(value = "Here")
# -> Value is missing:  FALSE value:  Here

# I expected this to print "Value is missing:  TRUE"
wrapper(value = NULL)
# -> Value is missing:  FALSE value:
```

Can anyone shed some light on this (and how I can fix the problem)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `missing` argument does not actually evaluate for null values, but checks if a value was specified as an argument to a function.

Below, `missing` isn't checking the value of `x`, but it is checking to see if `x` was provided as an argument to `is_missing`.

```r
is_missing <- function(x=NULL) {
  missing(x)
}

is_missing()
#> [1] TRUE

is_missing(x = NULL)
#> [1] FALSE
```

I'm not sure what your desired function might look like, but here's an example of a potential refactor:

```r
fun1 <- function(value = NULL) {
  if(is.null(value)) {
    miss <- TRUE
    print(paste0("value is missing: ", miss))
  } else {
    miss <- FALSE
    print(paste0("value is missing: ", miss, ". value = ", value))
  }
}

fun1(value = NULL)
#> [1] "value is missing: TRUE"
fun1()
#> [1] "value is missing: TRUE"
fun1(value = "X")
#> [1] "value is missing: FALSE. value = X"
```

Comment: Thanks - I think a combination does the trick for me:  `if (missing(value) || is.null(value)){ ... }`